# How to Get Google Now card information into my own app

Tags: android, google-now

I would like to make an app that pushes Google Now cards to the Pebble SmartWatch. Is there a way to access Google Now cards programmatically? I'm guessing from my googling that it's not officially supported, but have people found out any undocumented APIs that access this information?

Comment: It is two years since your question and the Google Now platform was opened a bit since then. So have you found any way to detect the cards and the info inside of them with this "new" Google Now?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there are no official or unofficial APIs as of now to retrieve the Google Now cards, and there are unlikely to be as it is a proprietary app by Google that gives them a competitive advantage, and not part of the AOSP Android.