# How to detect Google Now reminder and card

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-now

I am making an Android Wear app where I want to react to Google Now reminders and Google Now cards. I was hoping for something like calendar's `android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER` action but I cannot find any information about any events/actions that could be recieved via a `BroadcastReceiver` in a phone. I do not even receive any Gogole Now related notifications into the `NotificationListenerService`.

How can I detect these events? Is it possible at all? There is a more then two years old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766537/how-to-get-google-now-card-information-into-my-own-app) but with no recent information.